# Synonym for "factor"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym of "factor". "Factor" as a cause of something.

Example:

> X happened due to technical and social factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> X happened due to technical and social causes.
>
> X happened due to technical and social reasons.
>
> X happened due to technical and social circumstances.

I am no native speaker, so maybe not all of them would be used in real life (or are correct, for that matter).

Comment: I would say "X happened due to technical and social reasons."

Comment: Also, 'situations', 'conditions', 'phenomenon'.